# Is it possible to get the captcha token that would be sent in an http request?

Tags: http, request, token, recaptcha

Basically what the question is asking. When an http request is sent from a webpage after I click on a button, a captcha token is sent in the body of the request and I was wondering if there's any way I can know how that token is created so I can mimic the request

Comment: The token is deliberately heavily obfuscated, there is no feasible way you will ever recreate a valid token other than having the reCAPTCHA javascript code itself create one.

Comment: How can I access the javascript?

Comment: [This](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/instrument-web-pages#user-action) is the snippet of Javascript to use reCAPTCHA to generate a token, specifically the `grecaptcha.enterprise.execute()` call